Cannot overwrite value under /sys/class/power_supply/CMB0/charge_control_end_threshold - Ubuntu 22.04 (6.8.0-45-generic)
Some time ago I have created a simple script that will setup a battery charge limit on my laptop according to documentation.
I even modified crontab, so that it would remain between boots.
However, I think from some short time (maybe a day or two) I have noticed it stopped working. When I try to modify the /sys/class/power_supply/CMB0/charge_control_end_threshold it just reverts to 0 (does not matter if I run sudoedit or any other method)
I have previously noticed this behavior with different features described in the documenation page, but I just assumed they were not supported in a way.
Any comment or insight would be appreciated.
$ echo 80 | sudo tee /sys/class/power_supply/CMB0/charge_control_end_threshold 
[sudo] password for kornel: 
80
kornel@kornel-LG:~$ cat /sys/class/power_supply/CMB0/charge_control_end_threshold 
0

(as a note I have an LG Gram laptop)
EDIT:
If by any chance there is someone else who is having similar situation on Ubuntu, I have filed a bug report Here

That's a known kernel bug. You need at least kernel verision 6.10.7 https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/747

Exactly what I was looking for, would've accepted it as an answer, thanks :)

You're welcome.

That's a known kernel bug. You need at least kernel version 6.10.7. Refer to:
https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/747
